# How do I move a column forward then back again?

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

Trying to move an entire column from A-B then back in spreadsheets.

I have tried doing it like this,

```
function moveForward() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  sheet.getRange("A1:A").moveTo(sheet.getRange("B1")); 
}

function moveBack() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  sheet.getRange("B1:B").moveTo(sheet.getRange("A1"));
}
```

But it just deletes most of the column, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Explain *deletes most of the collum* in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is working as intended.

The only way I can see to make it delete the column is running two times the same function.

### Explanation:

- Your script contains two functions
- When you want to run one of them from the Apps Script editor, you have to chose which one you want to run before pressing the "play button"
- After you run function `moveForward()`, in order to run the function `moveBack()` - you need to select it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is I need the script to run on a time-driven trigger so it auto refreshes the ImportJSON cells, are you sure there is no way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely possible. But you can only bind a function rather than a script to a time-driven trigger. That is, if you have two functions, you need two triggers. Also, in order to avoid moving an empty column and overwriting with it the existing data, you can implement at the beginning of your functions a conditional statement to check either the column to be  moved contains data or is empty.